# How does app.use(express.static("public")) work with nested URL's?

Tags: node.js, express

I am quite new to node and I am trying to wrap my head around how the express.static middleware is working. In my views folder I have some href's like this:

`<link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

My application is able to grab these files form URLS's such as localhost/about, localhost/contact etc. However it will not grab files if the end point is something like localhost/form/new. Is express.static getting these static assets from localhost/somefile and when there is a nested URL it defaults to /form/somefile (which won't work)? I am aware that if you put a '/' before vendor it will work from any level, why is this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
app.use(express.static(“public”));
```

That is a way of saying "hey express, look if any incoming requests (like GET /bundle.css matches a file on that directory, if so, send it!".

Any file on that directory, you should be able to access under /. If you're serving from your localhost and have bundle.css on public folder, you can visit http://localhost/bundle.css.

Any asset you're trying to get from public folder, should start with / meaning look for an **absolute path** (in this case, the path public folder is serving which is /).

**Update**

There is another way of doing that using **relative path** which is not recommendable.

If you're in */about/index.html* and you're trying to get */css/bundle.css* (under public's folder)

**Absolute Path:**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bundle.css">
```

**Relative Path: (not recommendable)**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bundle.css">
```

Comment: @scottwsmyth updated the post, there's an relative path example (which is the another way to do it), It isn't recommendable to do it since you'd have to update all your paths if you were to change the html directory (let's say from /about/index.html to /about/contact/index.html)

Comment: Okay. So if you do "../" it will bring you back to public/css/bundle.css since public is being served via "/" route ?

Comment: @scottwsmyth  ".." means go up a folder. Answering your question yes, you'll go up a folder and then from there, go to css and then bundle.css

Comment: Yep. So why is this not recommended?

Comment: @scottwsmyth Imagine you have multiple files in your website (like index.html, about/index.html, post/index.html, admin/index.html, admin/settings/index.html) and then one day, you have to move a file from its current folder to another one's (that will screw up most relative paths since relative path describes the location of a file relative to your current working directory).

Using Absolute Path ensures that no matter wherever you are in your directory, (maybe ten folders below like /a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/j/index.html) you'll find /css/bundle.css if that file exists under public/ directory.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing to keep in mind is to make a slash mark before the static file address.

---

```html
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" type="text/css">
```

---

If you do not put this slash before the address, you will have a problem loading styles, images, etc. in the nested addresses.

For example, if you use the following addressing instead of the above operation, you will definitely have problems in the nested URL.

```html
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
```

---

This is especially useful on page 404.